# Убрать часть из URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Здравствуйте.
Допустим есть такой адрес http://demo.ru/album.html#prettyPhoto[pp_gal1]/0/
можно как-нибудь скрыть часть #prettyPhoto[pp_gal1]/0/ в URL. Эта часть добавляется плагином prettyphoto при просмотре изображений.

Comment: Что значит скрыть? Вам нужно просто получить URL без этой части или что?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev да без этой части

Comment: неужели нет способа как-то это убрать?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
   ...
   deeplinking: false,
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Получить часть URL без `#prettyPhoto...` можно с помощью регулярных выражений, например так:

```
var url = 'http://demo.ru/album.html#prettyPhoto[pp_gal1]/0/';
console.log(url.replace(/^([^#]+)#prettyPhoto.*$/, '$1'));
```

Другой вопрос, что вы будете с этим делать. Как уже сказал @Qwertiy, если эта строка добавляется в URL, значит она зачем-то нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя. Скрыть ничего нельзя можно только убрать.
Но раз оно добавляется, то зачем-то нужно.